# If i use String str = new String("test); 10 times, will it create an object 10 times?

Tags: java, string

In Java if i use `String str = new String("test);` 10 times, will it create an object 10 times in heap memory?

Or a reference is returned every time? Till now i have studied that new always creates a new object.

Comment: `new` creates an object. Always.

Comment: From documentation :

 **Instantiating a Class**
 
 The `new` operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new
 object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also
 invokes the object constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It will create 10 objects in memory.

Each time you call `new` operator, it gives you a pointer to object in heap. When you let go of that reference, it's garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll get 10 different references to different objects.